# Rename JSON key field with value in object

Tags: json, key-value, remap

Have the following json output:

```
[
{
    "id": "47",
    "canUpdate": true,
    "canDelete": true,
    "canArchive": true,
    "info": [
        {
            "key": "problem_type",
            "value": "PAN",
            "valueCaption": "PAN",
            "keyCaption": "Category"
        },
        {
            "key": "status",
            "value": 3,
            "valueCaption": "Closed",
            "keyCaption": "Status"
        },
        {
            "key": "insert_time",
            "value": 1466446314000,
            "valueCaption": "2016-06-20 14:11:54.0",
            "keyCaption": "Request time"
        }
```

As you can see under "info" they actually label the key:value pair as "key": "problem_type" and "value": "PAN" and then "valueCaption": "PAN" "keyCaption": "Category". What I need to do is remap the file so that, in this example, it shows as "problem_type": "PAN" and "Category": "PAN". What would be the best method to iterate through the output to remap the key:value pairs in this manner?

How it needs to be:

```
[
{
    "id": "47",
    "canUpdate": true,
    "canDelete": true,
    "canArchive": true,
    "info": [
        {
            "problem_type": "PAN",
            "Category": "PAN"
        },
        {
            "status": 3,
            "Status": "Closed"
        },
        {
            "insert_time": 1466446314000,
            "Request time": "2016-06-20 14:11:54.0"
        }
```

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Tag that please.

Comment: Pulling json data from Linux server using a Bash script on a Linux server. Same server will also run script to convert file after it is retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) solution which uses [Update assignment |=](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:|=)

```
.[].info[] |= {(.key):.value, (.keyCaption):.valueCaption}
```

Sample Run (assumes data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M '.[].info[] |= {(.key):.value, (.keyCaption):.valueCaption}' data.json
[
  {
    "id": "47",
    "canUpdate": true,
    "canDelete": true,
    "canArchive": true,
    "info": [
      {
        "problem_type": "PAN",
        "Category": "PAN"
      },
      {
        "status": 3,
        "Status": "Closed"
      },
      {
        "insert_time": 1466446314000,
        "Request time": "2016-06-20 14:11:54.0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/xLb30v0X5T)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Works perfectly.